# How can I append data from a old dataframe onto a new, blank dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to do something relatively simple, create a blank dataframe and add a new dataframe to it, however this won't work, everything I have looked at has told me to due it this way with append. However, it is not working.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
new = pd.DataFrame()
new2 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]], columns = ["H", "I"])  
new.append(new2, ignore_index=True)
print(new)
```

And I just get:

Empty DataFrame

```
Columns: [ ]

Index: [ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `append` operation like below

```
import pandas as pd
new = pd.DataFrame()
new2 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]], columns = ["H", "I"])  
new = new.append(new2, ignore_index=True)
print(new)
```

Output:

```
   H  I
0  A  1
1  B  2
2  C  3
```

Alternate way using `pd.concat`

```
new = pd.concat([new, new2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, `pandas` methods do not change input dataframes in place. Where available, you need to pass `inplace=True`; otherwise, reassign to your original variable (that's what you need here):

```
import pandas as pd
new = pd.DataFrame()
new2 = pd.DataFrame([["A", 1], ["B", 2], ["C", 3]], columns = ["H", "I"])  
new = new.append(new2, ignore_index=True)

print(new)
```

Output:

```
   H  I
0  A  1
1  B  2
2  C  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value back to new:

```
In [41]: new = new.append(new2, ignore_index=True)
```